# DataTable edit is not displayed correctly

Tags: c#, datatable, instance, edit

I have been searching for an answer to my problem for quite some time now and I haven't found a solution. PS: I am working on a Quiz game in German, so you might not be able to understand the variable names etc., but I think that shouldn't be the problem.

I have a DataTable with 8 columns in the class `SQL`, and in the last column there is a 0.

```
namespace Quiz
{
    class SQL
    {
        public static DataTable GEO_Fragen()
        {
            using (DataTable GEO = new DataTable("Geografie"))
            {

                GEO.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
                GEO.Columns.Add("Frage", typeof(string));
                GEO.Columns.Add("Antwort 1", typeof(string));
                GEO.Columns.Add("Antwort 2", typeof(string));
                GEO.Columns.Add("Antwort 3", typeof(string));
                GEO.Columns.Add("Antwort 4", typeof(string));
                GEO.Columns.Add("Richtige Antwort", typeof(int));
                GEO.Columns.Add("Gefragt", typeof(int));

                GEO.Rows.Add(0, "Question", "Answer 1", "Answer 2", "Answer 3", "Answer 4", 4, 0);
                GEO.Rows.Add(1, "Question", "Answer 1", "Answer 2", "Answer 3", "Answer 4", 4, 0);
                GEO.Rows.Add(2, "Question", "Answer 1", "Answer 2", "Answer 3", "Answer 4", 4, 0);
                GEO.Rows.Add(3, "Question", "Answer 1", "Answer 2", "Answer 3", "Answer 4", 4, 0);
                GEO.Rows.Add(4, "Question", "Answer 1", "Answer 2", "Answer 3", "Answer 4", 4, 0);
                GEO.Rows.Add(5, "Question", "Answer 1", "Answer 2", "Answer 3", "Answer 4", 4, 0);
                GEO.Rows.Add(6, "Question", "Answer 1", "Answer 2", "Answer 3", "Answer 4", 4, 0);
                GEO.Rows.Add(7, "Question", "Answer 1", "Answer 2", "Answer 3", "Answer 4", 4, 0);
                GEO.Rows.Add(8, "Question", "Answer 1", "Answer 2", "Answer 3", "Answer 4", 4, 0);
                GEO.Rows.Add(9, "Question", "Answer 1", "Answer 2", "Answer 3", "Answer 4", 4, 0);
                GEO.Rows.Add(10, "Question", "Answer 1", "Answer 2", "Answer 3", "Answer 4", 4, 0);
                GEO.Rows.Add(11, "Question", "Answer 1", "Answer 2", "Answer 3", "Answer 4", 4, 0);
                GEO.Rows.Add(12, "Question", "Answer 1", "Answer 2", "Answer 3", "Answer 4", 4, 0);
                GEO.Rows.Add(13, "Question", "Answer 1", "Answer 2", "Answer 3", "Answer 4", 4, 0);
                GEO.Rows.Add(14, "Question", "Answer 1", "Answer 2", "Answer 3", "Answer 4", 4, 0);
                GEO.Rows.Add(15, "Question", "Answer 1", "Answer 2", "Answer 3", "Answer 4", 4, 0);
                GEO.Rows.Add(16, "Question", "Answer 1", "Answer 2", "Answer 3", "Answer 4", 4, 0);
                GEO.Rows.Add(17, "Question", "Answer 1", "Answer 2", "Answer 3", "Answer 4", 4, 0);
                GEO.Rows.Add(18, "Question", "Answer 1", "Answer 2", "Answer 3", "Answer 4", 4, 0);
                GEO.Rows.Add(19, "Question", "Answer 1", "Answer 2", "Answer 3", "Answer 4", 4, 0);

                return GEO;
            }
        }
        //...more code
```

In another class, I am choosing a random question. If this question has a "1" in the last column (meaning it has been used before), it generates another one.

```
public void Zufallszahl()
{
    zufall = rnd.Next(0, SQL.GEO_Fragen().Rows.Count);
    if (SQL.GEO_Fragen().Rows[zufall]["Gefragt"].ToString() == "1")
    {
        Zufallszahl();
    }
    else
    {
        lbl_Frage.Text = SQL.GEO_Fragen().Rows[zufall]["Frage"].ToString(); //Filling in a random Question and Answers
        rad_Antwort1.Text = SQL.GEO_Fragen().Rows[zufall]["Antwort 1"].ToString();
        rad_Antwort2.Text = SQL.GEO_Fragen().Rows[zufall]["Antwort 2"].ToString();
        rad_Antwort3.Text = SQL.GEO_Fragen().Rows[zufall]["Antwort 3"].ToString();
        rad_Antwort4.Text = SQL.GEO_Fragen().Rows[zufall]["Antwort 4"].ToString();

        rad_Antwort1.Checked = false; // No radio button is ticked
        rad_Antwort2.Checked = false;
        rad_Antwort3.Checked = false;
        rad_Antwort4.Checked = false;
    }
}
```

And now to the real problem: When I am changing the value of the last column in the row I chose randomly, it is doing so really shortly in the debugging mode. But right after that, when I let me show the value of this cell, it shows "0" again.

```
private void btn_Weiter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rad_Antwort1.Checked == true || rad_Antwort2.Checked == true || rad_Antwort3.Checked == true || rad_Antwort4.Checked == true)
    {
        Pruefen(); // Checking the chosen answer
        lbl_Score.Text = "Punkte: " + Punkte; // Current points
        string kontrolle = SQL.GEO_Fragen().Rows[zufall]["Antwort 1"].ToString();
        SQL.GEO_Fragen().Rows[zufall]["Gefragt"] = 1; //Changing value of the last column in row "zufall" to "1"
        MessageBox.Show(SQL.GEO_Fragen().Rows[zufall]["Gefragt"].ToString()); //Shows "0" instead of "1"

        if (rad_Antwort1.Text == kontrolle) // Next question
        {
            Zufallszahl();
            while (Counter <= 10)
            {
                Counter = Counter + 1;
                break;
            }

            if (Counter > 10)
            {
                SQL.GEO_Fragen().Reset();
                btn_Weiter.Hide(); // After 10 questions back to main menu
                lbl_Frage.Hide();
                rad_Antwort1.Hide();
                rad_Antwort2.Hide();
                rad_Antwort3.Hide();
                rad_Antwort4.Hide();
                lbl_Titel.Show();
                lbl_Themen.Show();
                rad_Geografie.Show();
                rad_Geschichte.Show();
                rad_Serien.Show();
                rad_Videospiele.Show();
                btn_Start.Show();
            }
            //... more code
```

I have tried many different things, i have tried it with `AcceptChanges()`, `BeginEdit()` and `EndEdit()`. Just for debugging purposes i have also tried to put the DataTable and the edit-command into one method. The editing then works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you call your `GEO_Fragen()` method it is creating a new instance of the DataTable. So you are updating one instance and checking a completely different instance, which is why it appears to not be updating.

You could implement the Singleton design pattern by adding a static field and property to your `SQL` class:

```
private static DataTable geoFragenInstance;

public static DataTable GeoFragenInstance
{
   get 
   {
      if (geoFragenInstance == null)
      {
          geoFragenInstance = GEO_Fragen();
      } 

      return geoFragenInstance;
   }
}
```

To ensure there is only ever one instance of `SQL` you should also add a private default constructor:

```
private SQL() {}
```

Otherwise you will get a public one by default.

I would also make your `GEO_Fragen()` method `private`

Then replace all your references to `SQL.GEO_Fragen()` with `SQL.GeoFragenInstance`

Please note this is the simplest implementation of the Singleton and amongst other things is not thread-safe (which might be fine for your purposes).

Further reading here:

[Implementing Singleton in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff650316.aspx)

[Design Patterns - Singleton Pattern (4 Examples)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Singleton-Pattern-24a1da7f)

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems like it worked! Sorry for not answering quicker, I had much to get done :).

Comment: No probs, @Racer4443, I know what you mean ;) & glad to be of assistance :)